# How to catch SQLLite trigger Raised event

Tags: java, sqlite, exception, triggers

I have a trigger on my sqllite database that works just fine.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER no_name_duplicate " +
        " BEFORE INSERT "+
        " ON "+profileTable+

        " FOR EACH ROW BEGIN"+
        " SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT "+colProfileName+" FROM "+profileTable+" WHERE "+colProfileName+"=new."+colProfileName+" ) IS NOT NULL)"+
        " THEN RAISE (ABORT,'My Violation') END;"+
        "  END;");
```

Raises event

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: My Violation(code 19)
```

Now how would you go about if you would want to catch that exception (or edit the above code) to  display a message or log something.

To sum up, how would I get this `Log.v("test","test")` to fire when that trigger fires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this I found was to return the rowID.

```
long newRowId;
newRowId = db.insert(tableName,primaryKey,values);
```

If that trigger fires you will get a row id of -1. Then just show your message or log whatever when you get a row id of -1

Comment: Have you heard of [insertOrThrow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)?

Comment: Yes, that will throw an exception, but you wont be able to know if it has thrown anything if you don't get the rowId. That will only throw or insert something. What if you want to display a message, or populate a textbox when it is thrown.